# Conversion of body wave magnitude to moment magnitude

Tags: earthquakes

I have been tasked with homogenizing a catalog of events obtained from the USGS website, however, the data is a mix of different type of magnitude measures. How do I convert the different type of magnitude to moment magnitude and what do they depend on? Is it a pure empirical relationship?